# Having issue using IMPORTRANGE with QUERY to transfer specific data off one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I currently have the following google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bmnrdzcZhnQbTychErVVWE7BRGQkJdXb0a17xnupbiE/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to create a new spreadsheet that imports the data from the March 2022 tab that is marked "Apex" in the "Group" or N column while only taking columns 1,2,3,4,5, 13, 15, 16. I have tried a number of formulas but getting nowhere.

Here is the spreadsheet I am trying to import the data to:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QyAaXh3wLGHQr056vutV6h0KU8LkKjTIa_XmqqO4gzA/edit?usp=sharing

Also, strangly, when I do
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bmnrdzcZhnQbTychErVVWE7BRGQkJdXb0a17xnupbiE/edit?pli=1#gid=1680963029", "March 2022!A1:N5000"),"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col13, Col14")
I am at least able to get the data imported, but once I add Col15 inside the formula and on, I get a #Value error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col15" which is weird considering there's definitely data in Col15 and onwards.

Regardless, I need a formula that can not only successfully import all the columns I specify into the new sheet, but a formula that can then filter just the data that in Col14 = "APEX"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apologies! Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bmnrdzcZhnQbTychErVVWE7BRGQkJdXb0a17xnupbiE/edit?pli=1#gid=1680963029", "March 2022!A1:O5000"),"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col13, Col14, Col15")
```

The reason why you get the error "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col15" " is because on your original formula `March 2022!A1:N5000` only counts as 14 columns.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]